# Working with pyserial: printing result

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, hardware, pyserial

I have the following concerns with the code below:

1. How would i be able to print out the result of what is received such as if i type status1 it should return close1/open1? The USB Controller that I am working with that has locks connected to them has a set of commands that can be communicated through ASCII.Such as if I send the command status1, it should communicate back open1/close1.
2. In the condition line `if (ser.isOpen() == False):` it does not exactly check to see if the port is open as even when nothing is connected it bypasses that line and tries to send a command which obviously returns an error

Below is the code (I am using python 3 but some of the code was based on python 2):

```
import serial

#Using  pyserial Library to establish connection
#Global Variables
ser = 0

#Initialize Serial Port
def serial_connection():
    COMPORT = 3
    global ser
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.baudrate = 38400 #Suggested rate in Southco documentation, both locks and program must be at same rate
    ser.port = COMPORT - 1 #counter for port name starts at 0




    #check to see if port is open or closed
    if (ser.isOpen() == False):
        print ('The Port %d is Open '%COMPORT + ser.portstr)
          #timeout in seconds
        ser.timeout = 10
        ser.open()

    else:
        print ('The Port %d is closed ' %COMPORT)


#call the serial_connection() function
serial_connection()
ser.write(b'close2\r\n')
```

Thanks in advance and for any clarification, kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on 1) You'll have to make your methods that connect to the serial port to send a command wait for a reply, and timeout if one isn't received in a reasonable time. Hopefully the replies from the lock have a consistent terminating character like carriage-return so you can spot this and decode the string you have received to check for open1/close1. You'll have to allow time for the characters of the command to be sent, a bit of a delay then time for the characters of the reply with terminating carriage-return. If much longer than that passes and you haven't got a response then timeout and return a failure. I've done this sort of thing using a Python statemachine, running in a separate thread so the main program can carry on paying attention to the user.

on 2)

The line

if (ser.isOpen() == False):

A style thing - isOpen is a reasonably clear method name that will return true if the port is open. Rather than comparing with False, it's probably clearer to use if ser.isOpen(): or if not ser.isOpen(). Looking at your code, it's difficult to see what you are trying to achieve - is it that if the port is not open you want to open it? In that case the logic should be:

```
if not ser.isOpen():
    print ('The Port %d is **closed - opening** Stephan: '%COMPORT + ser.portstr)
      #timeout in seconds
    ser.timeout = 10
    ser.open()

else:
    print ('The Port %d is **open** Stephan' %COMPORT)
```

Either way, your serial_connection() function returns and your calling code calls ser.write(), so the behaviour you describe in 2 isn't surprising.

Comment: Also note that serial ports can't usually tell if they are actually connected to something - unless e.g. you know that the device you connected to has non-default settings for the extra status lines like RTS/CTS. And by their nature of being plugged in, they can be unplugged, or power fail, so when you send a command you have to wait a while to see if anything comes back, and gracefully handle partial responses too.

Comment: Good way to debug serial ports is to connect your PC running python to a terminal (e.g. another PC) or by using a virtual serial port like com0com you can connect a terminal app on your PC to a virtual port that your app is talking to. Then you can pretend to be the lock device (extend timeouts to allow time for human response delays).